# How to avoid duplicate content stored in MySQL database submitted by user

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am creating a site that lets users list up to 5 companies they are associated with. When other users search these companies, all users associated with that company will show up in the search results.

The companies will be submitted by the users through a text input field.

How do I avoid users submitting duplicate companies? E.g. if UserA submits a company called stackoverflow, then UserB comes and also submits stackoverflow, there will be 2 stackoverflows in my database.

I have 3 tables:

**Users Table**

id|username|email

**Company Table**

id|company name

**UsersCompany Table**

id|userID|companyID

I'm using Laravel 5

Comment: Add a unique index on `company name` in your `company` table.

Comment: if i add a unique index, will other users still be able to add the same company to their list of the companies their associated with. I want the companies to be assigned to more than one user, I just don't want duplicates in the database.

Comment: @Luna create an autocomplete on the frontend that communicates to the server and fetches all available companies as the user types the name in. And Loufylouf's suggestion is correct, unique index is the way to go here. Assigning a single company to multiple users should be possible with your current database design, you just need to code it so that it creates that relationship.

Answer (score 4):

You should really use [Laravel Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic) and keyword `unique` to handle this:

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'company' => 'required|unique:company|max:255'
]);
```

Also, you could use custom Request class to handle [form validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#form-request-validation):

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'company' => 'required|unique|max:255'
    ];
}
```

If I were you, I'd use second one.

Comment: Good answer, but it must conjugated with unique index and methodology for entering names because Stackoverflow, StackOverFlow, Stack over flow, etc are not equal. The more simple entry methodology is transforming string to lower case.

Comment: @sємsєм MySQL is actually [case insensitive by default](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case-sensitivity.html), and I imagine the laravel unique uses db equality.

Comment: same as another answer, the validate method renders the view with errors, but doesn't store the data if validation fails

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with a simple check. If the company does not exists create a new Company or attach the Company to the user.

I assume the companies are submitted in one single text input seperated by commas and you have setup your relations correct. If not check [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships).

Example:

```
// Inside your controller
public function post_something(Request $request)
{

    // Always good to validate
    $this->validate(....);

    // Somehow get your user model
    $user = ....

    // Get companies input and loop
    $company_names = $request->input('company_names');

    $company_names = explode(',', $company_names );

    foreach ($company_names as $company_name)
    {
        $company = Company::firstOrCreate(['company_name' => $company_name]);

        $user->companies()->attach($company);        
    }

    // Your other stuff
    //
    ....

}
```

Comment: didn't read the docs, just assumed it works like Model::where('bla', $bla)->first();

Answer (score 3):

This can achieve this by
 either  creating PRIMARY Key or UNIQUE on company_Name

```
  ALTER TABLE company_Table ADD PRIMARY KEY(company_Name)

  ALTER TABLE company_Table ADD UNIQUE (company_Name)
```

or

```
    IF NOT EXISTS(QUERY) Then INSERT
```

or
    Create BEFORE INSERT trigger .

```
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a unique index on the table. So if your column is named `company_name` and table is `companies` you could execute the following:

`alter table companies add unique (company_name)`

Or alternatively you can do a query in programming before you allow an insert, which checks if the entry already exists. Or a combination of both..

Answer (score 2):

you can use unique key for companies table
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/constraint-primary-key.html

Answer (score 2):

This is very easily obtainable, by using `UNIQUE` in MySQL.

```
ALTER TABLE  `company_Table` ADD UNIQUE (
   `company_Name`
   )
```

By putting this into MySQL, the company_Name column becomes `UNIQUE`, meaning there can only be one. If you attempt to insert another one, an error returns.

`UNIQUE` can also be used on member emails on a userbase, if you don't want somebody to log in with the same email. `UNIQUE` is also perfect for POST_IDs, MEMBER_IDs, COMMENT_IDs, and several others, that could become very useful on a blog, forum, or social media site.

If you would like to create the `UNIQUE` key upon creating this table, here is how you would do so:

```
   CREATE TABLE Company_Table
(
ID int NOT NULL,
Company_Name varchar(255),
UNIQUE (Company_Name)
)
```

W3schools has a good tutorial on this: [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp)

Answer (score 2):

On my opinion you should use Eloquent `firstOrCreate` method
If you will use this approach, then you even no need any "unique" validation under the companies.

### Lets start

**DB Schema**

```
users
id
username

companies
id
company_name

user_company
id
user_id
company_id
```

**Models** (only relations methods)

User.php

```
public function companies()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('NAMESPACE_TO_YOUR_MODEL\Company');
    /*you can set foreign keys fields if it's not canonical see docs*/
}
```

Company.php

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('NAMESPACE_TO_YOUR_MODEL\User');
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function store(CompanyRequest $request)
{
    $companiesFromRequest = $request->get('companies'); 
    // it's just for example, you can retreive companies from request with any other approach
    $companiesId = [];
    foreach ($companiesFromRequest as $company) {
        // assumes that $company variable contains all or at least part of info,
        // that need to create or identify particuliar comapny 
        $c = Company::firstOrCreate($company);
        $companiesId[] = $c->id;
    }
    // in this case we just retreive existing user
    $user = User::findOrFail($request->get('user_id'));

    $user->companies()->sync($companiesId);

    // or you can use 
    // $user->companies()->attach($companiesId);
    // difference between this commands you can found in official laravel docs

    return redirect('any/place/you/wish')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Application Layer:
Use Laravel's Validation property 'unique' to establish that only unique company name is allowed.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'company_name' => 'required|unique:companies|max:255',
    ]);

   // The company name is valid, store in database...
}
```

Database Layer:
add a constraint as unique to the migration of the company's table for company_name column.

```
$table->string('company_name')->unique();
```

Comment: This approach prevents stops the execution of the rest of the code if the company name exists, op wants to reuse the company name and associate that to another user.

Answer (score 1):

found the answer in larval i just use firstOrNew() Creation Method
will attempt to locate a record in the database matching the given attributes. However, if a model is not found, a new model instance will be returned. Note that the model returned by firstOrNew has not yet been persisted to the database. You will need to call save manually to persist it:

[as stated here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#mass-assignment)

Comment: use `firstOrCreate()` to persist the model automatically

Answer (score 1):

Try to build schema as following to get optimum performance.This structure helps you to avoid duplicate data and also do code validations in Laravel to avoid malicious inputs.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Users Table` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Company Table` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `company name` (`company name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Users Company Table` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `companyID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `userID` (`userID`),
  KEY `companyID` (`companyID`),
  CONSTRAINT `Users Company Table_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`userID`) REFERENCES `Users Table` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `Users Company Table_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`companyID`) REFERENCES `Company Table` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this code helps you. This is a sql code to insert unique data

```
INSERT INTO UsersCompanyTable (userID, companyID)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT $_POST("user_id"), $_POST("company_id")) AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT companyID FROM UsersCompanyTable WHERE companyID = $_POST("company_id")
) LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should allow user to select company, and then simply give reference of `UserID`, `CompanyID` tables in  UsersCompany Table. So you will always have a unique record if UserA insert StackOverFlow and UserB also insert StackOverFlow, in your database. It will be like:

- 1-UserA-StackOverflow
- 2-UserB-StackOverFlow.

Or, if you want user to enter the company, check if the same company exists or not:

```
var checkcompany= "select * from Company Table where company name=company name"
```

Than check

```
if(checkcompany ! =null)
```

Than insert the record or else ignore it.