# Connect users with tags they create without having duplicate content in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5

I want to allow users to enter up to 5 tags tag like a company name, or charity their associated with. When a user clicks on that tag, it will take them to a page with all the users associated with that tag.

example: If somebody enters CBS, it will show all users associated with CBS.

I know I can add a unique index to keep users from entering duplicate content like stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36166925/how-to-avoid-duplicate-content-stored-in-mysql-database-submitted-by-user) , but won't that keep users from being able to enter a company they are associated with if it already exist in the database.

I don't wan't duplicates in the database, but do wan't to allow users the choice to pick companies that may already exists in the database submitted from other users.

This database will hold only data submitted from the users.

I am using larval 5

my database looks like this:

**Users**

id|username|email

**Tags**

id|tags

**usertags**

id|userId|tagId

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what are you asking for, but if you set Tags.tags as unique, it should prevent users to enter a company that already exists.

Comment: "but do wan't to allow users the choice" To clarify: You *do* want users to choice? If so, then do a $tag = Tag::where('tag',$input)->get(); to see if a tag with that ID already exists. if it does, then assign that ID.

Comment: As per my understanding, you want to disallow duplication in `Tags` table by making `tags` column *unique* **AND** you then want a unique index in `usertags` table by using `[userId,tagId]` fields. This way you also avoid duplicating the same User-Company association but allow other users to choose the same Company.

Comment: Yes, thanks , exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the validate in request file of laravel
Use Unique based on the tag(and/or)comment & user id
It will help you to get data what you are expecting
refer laravel document also